# Adding value to the last cell

Tags: excel

I need help with something, in theory at least, simple:

You enter any value in one cell (A1), that value is added to B1. You add another value (replacing the previous value) in A1, C1 is created with that value, and goes on.

I need to keep that history saved, but at the same time, simplifying the input method.

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: You would need VBA for this.  What code have you tried?

Comment: I don't know VBA, i tried to put some things i found together, but i can't customize the code for my needs. Something like this: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
If IsNumeric(Target) Then
Range("B1") = Target.Value + 2
End If
End If
End Sub

Comment: Are you speaking specifically of cell A1 or any cell in column A? Should everything except column A (or cell A1) be protected from edits/additions/deletions?

Comment: No, i would use an entire column with this function. Row by row. the row would increase as you enter data and i have other columns that must be editable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, N As Long
    Set A = Range("A1")
    If Intersect(Target, A) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        N = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        Cells(1, N).Value = A.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

**EDIT#1**

**Remove the first version** and replace it with:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, N As Long, WhichRow As Long
    Set A = Range("A:A")
    If Intersect(Target, A) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        WhichRow = Target.Row
        N = Cells(WhichRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        Cells(WhichRow, N).Value = Target.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Whoa, that's magical. Almosta perfect, but can it work for every cell in a certain column and write in the same row as the selected cell? sorry if i'm asking too much, your help is already awesome. thanks!

Comment: That's perfect, you're a hero. thanks very, very much.